# Gauss Theorem for Electrostatics : Why is $D_r$ considered constant?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration

Gauss Law states that $\int \vec D. d\vec s = Q_{enclosed}$
Consider the spherical case with $\rho_v = cst$ *-- for the sake of not doing an integral on other side.*
Now the proof I was reading says that since $d\vec s $ is normal the surface it would be the $\vec R$ direction and $d\vec s = R^2 sin(\theta)\  d\theta \ d\phi \ \vec a_r$ and the only component present from $\vec D $ is $Dr\ \vec a_r $ and here is what confused me when doing the intergral they pulled $D_r$ from the integral as such $$D_r \int d\vec s$$ what made them sure that $D_r $ is not a function of $\phi$ and $\theta$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just the case for the limited examples where Gauss' Law is actually useful to solve the problem. Though it is always true, it does not make it any easier to find the electric field if we need to integrate the LH side as well.

If we have a source that is spherically symmetric, such as a point charge or sphere of charge with at least angular uniformity, then we know that at a given radius, the field is independent of the angular position and so we can bring D outside the integral.

This is why there is a fairly narrow scope of questions for which the field can be found exactly using this simple method, because it relied on some type of spherical, cylindrical or planar symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I’m not convinced though. Mathematically and physically when you do such thing you are actually assuming that the field density is independent of  phi and theta. Who said so ? What if we have a field who’s R component depends on theta or phi ? It’s still the same surface being studied just different field.

Comment: That is why we can only consider this for specific fields where we know that there is symmetry. Consider for example a uniformly charged sphere. If the sphere is perfectly round and uniformly charged, then the field should be the same in any direction of as long as we are at the same distance. The charge has rotational symmetry, so if I rotate the object by any angle it will still look the same (since the charge is distributed uniformly). So for cases such as this one the field extends outward radially. It is the symmetry of the charge distribution that causes this.

Comment: @HasanHammoud - The point is that when there is no reason for any dependence on direction, because all directions are equivalent, you can  assume that the field is symmetrical and independent of $\phi$ and $\theta$.